# Styling a default tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using jQuery, I have implemented tooltip in my html. Now I want to style my tooltip.

How can I do that?

My JavaScript code for the tooltip is this:

```
$('.bootstrap-switch-handle-on').hover(function () {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer')
           .attr('title', 'This is a hover text.');
}, function () {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I think that the best option would be using css.

Comment: how to apply that css

Comment: Do you have a `css` file in your project?

Comment: yes I have but I have no idea how ho apply css on tool tip I have applied css on contorls only

Comment: `.bootstrap-switch-handle-on:hover { /styles }`.

Comment: add a class to your tooltip and use css for styling that. If I were you, I'd like the tooltip by myself not using plugins.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just adding the `title` attribute to the `.bootstrap-switch-handle-on` element.  The subsequent "tooltip" is generated by the browser and cannot be styled.  If you are using Bootstrap, you can use their built in Tooltip which can be styled with CSS.  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips